# Return Label Text From Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gravity-forms-plugin

I've been trying to have my eventLabel value equal my Gravity Form label. Currently my code is pulling the 'name' attribute from the input field of my form. However, I'm looking to pull the label text prior to the span element.

```
<li id="field_38_1" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_38_1">
        "Name"
        <span class="gfield_required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
        <input name="input_1" id="input_38_1" type="text" value="" class="medium"  tabindex="1002">
    </div>
</li>
```

I've tried this and it hasn't worked. It only returns [object Object]. Thoughts?

```
dataLayer.push({'eventCategory': 'Form - ' +
$(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
   'eventAction': 'completed',
   'eventLabel': $(this).parents('li').find('label'),
   'event': 'gaEvent'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify

```
$(this).parents('li').find('label')
```

to

```
$(this).parents('li').find('label').text()
```

Comment: This worked! I thought I had tried this at some point, but nope. Thank you!